# Not getting 100% utilization out of CPU when using OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am using OpenMP to parallelize a for loop in my code by adding "#pragma omp parallel for" before the for loop. The code runs without producing any errors, but I have noticed that the core utilization is not constant throughout the execution. At the beginning, I get 100% utilization on all threads, but as the execution continues, this number drops to ~70% for all threads. I monitored this behavior using htop (I am running on a Linux machine). At the beginning, all of the threads show green bars with 100% on the right. After sometimes, the green starts to decrease and some red starts to creep up like this:

[image]

I have looked and saw that the red shows up whenever kernel threads are used. However, I still do not understand why it shows up in the first place. This behavior only occurs when the for loop is parallelized. When I take out the #pragma statement, the code runs at 100% throughout. My for loop has the following format:

```
  double xe1, ye1, ze1, te1, e1;
  double xe2, ye2, ze2, te2, e2;
  double xi1, yi1, zi1, ti1;
  double xi2, yi2, zi2, ti2;
  bool calculate_signal = true;
  time_t loop_start, loop_end;
  int max = omp_get_max_threads();
  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_num_threads(max);
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int k = 0; k < index; k++) {
    time(&loop_start);
    AvalancheMicroscopic aval;
    aval.SetSensor(&sensor);
    aval.EnableSignalCalculation(calculate_signal);
 
    aval.AvalancheElectron(electrons.at(k*4 + 0),electrons.at(k*4 + 1),electrons.at(k*4 + 2),electrons.at(k*4 + 3), 0.1, 0,0,0);
    int np = aval.GetNumberOfElectronEndpoints();
    DriftLineRKF drift;
    drift.SetSensor(&sensor);
    drift.EnableSignalCalculation(calculate_signal);
    
    for (int j = np; j--;) {
      aval.GetElectronEndpoint(j, xe1, ye1, ze1, te1, e1, 
                                  xe2, ye2, ze2, te2, e2, status);
      drift.DriftIon(xe1, ye1, ze1, te1);
    }
    time(&loop_end);
    std::cout << "Time for " << np << " electrons: " << double(loop_end - loop_start) << std::endl;
  }
```

This code is written using a toolkit called Garfield++ (https://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/; https://gitlab.cern.ch/garfield/garfieldpp/-/tree/master/). Here, electrons() is a 1d vector that holds coordinates. The index variable that can range from 1 to 7000 depending on the user. I have ran with index = 1000 and index = 200 and gotten the same behavior. Also, np can range from 1 to ~2000 and is something that is determined by the outer loop, so user has no control over this.

I have tried schedule(dynamic), but that didn't seem to help. Any insight into what caused this kind of behavior and how to fix it is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 1: The code is edited to provide more details.

Edit 2: I ran the code again to find the average time it takes for each loop. The answer, as expected, is not very straightforward (at least not for me). The code were run twice: one without parallelization (#pragma statement is commented out) and one with parallelization. Both executions were run by using the same electrons vector. Below, I have printed the time (in unit of seconds) each loop takes. The amount of time it takes to finished the inner loop is on the right side of the semicolon, while the number on the left of the semicolon np. I calculated the time by using time_t. I edited the above code to show what I did. Also, another thing to note is that the first case (w/o parallel) took 6065 sec to run while the second case took 2183 sec.

```
Using 1 core                        Using 10 cores
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1 electrons: 11
Time for 1565 electrons: 91         Time for 1 electrons: 0
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 1 electrons: 10
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 92 electrons: 12
Time for 3229 electrons: 162        Time for 1 electrons: 12
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1 electrons: 12
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 397 electrons: 21
Time for 1 electrons: 6             Time for 563 electrons: 41
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 902 electrons: 79
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 572 electrons: 18
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1 electrons: 14
Time for 2028 electrons: 103        Time for 1207 electrons: 80
Time for 898 electrons: 57          Time for 391 electrons: 4
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1392 electrons: 1
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 297 electrons: 9
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1439 electrons: 39
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 1 electrons: 14
Time for 1739 electrons: 91         Time for 1 electrons: 13
Time for 1977 electrons: 99         Time for 1 electrons: 14
Time for 3053 electrons: 152        Time for 393 electrons: 21
Time for 166 electrons: 20          Time for 543 electrons: 31
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 1767 electrons: 38
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 744 electrons: 5
Time for 573 electrons: 39          Time for 436 electrons: 44
Time for 31 electrons: 16           Time for 2444 electrons: 19
Time for 774 electrons: 51          Time for 2469 electrons: 4
Time for 680 electrons: 44          Time for 368 electrons: 30
Time for 514 electrons: 36          Time for 895 electrons: 29
Time for 1281 electrons: 69         Time for 2223 electrons: 6
Time for 2847 electrons: 148        Time for 1 electrons: 8
Time for 1004 electrons: 57         Time for 1394 electrons: 9
Time for 1422 electrons: 76         Time for 1 electrons: 4
Time for 762 electrons: 48          Time for 3283 electrons: 9
Time for 1817 electrons: 96         Time for 1 electrons: 3
Time for 2133 electrons: 110        Time for 1 electrons: 11
Time for 895 electrons: 52          Time for 1010 electrons: 5
Time for 939 electrons: 55          Time for 1 electrons: 12
Time for 743 electrons: 44          Time for 484 electrons: 5
Time for 1121 electrons: 63         Time for 112 electrons: 19
Time for 2482 electrons: 126        Time for 733 electrons: 0
Time for 1449 electrons: 79         Time for 1 electrons: 14
Time for 2037 electrons: 106        Time for 143 electrons: 9
Time for 4227 electrons: 204        Time for 1 electrons: 11
Time for 611 electrons: 39          Time for 394 electrons: 36
Time for 738 electrons: 44          Time for 1489 electrons: 3
Time for 1416 electrons: 75         Time for 540 electrons: 66
Time for 519 electrons: 39          Time for 1 electrons: 13
Time for 676 electrons: 45          Time for 1835 electrons: 27
Time for 497 electrons: 36          Time for 837 electrons: 5
Time for 303 electrons: 27          Time for 559 electrons: 18
Time for 2695 electrons: 144        Time for 828 electrons: 8
Time for 120 electrons: 18          Time for 811 electrons: 28
Time for 142 electrons: 19          Time for 136 electrons: 49
Time for 809 electrons: 48          Time for 1881 electrons: 9
Time for 27 electrons: 14           Time for 1 electrons: 12
Time for 343 electrons: 26          Time for 816 electrons: 13
Time for 168 electrons: 19          Time for 651 electrons: 2
Time for 78 electrons: 15           Time for 1 electrons: 11
Time for 883 electrons: 50          Time for 878 electrons: 18
Time for 563 electrons: 36          Time for 361 electrons: 14
Time for 418 electrons: 30          Time for 2581 electrons: 26
Time for 808 electrons: 46          Time for 155 electrons: 10
Time for 1977 electrons: 96         Time for 518 electrons: 50
Time for 610 electrons: 38          Time for 1241 electrons: 8
Time for 326 electrons: 26          Time for 722 electrons: 4
Time for 84 electrons: 16           Time for 223 electrons: 6
Time for 3116 electrons: 145        Time for 362 electrons: 10
Time for 979 electrons: 53          Time for 865 electrons: 15
Time for 259 electrons: 24          Time for 1 electrons: 10
Time for 761 electrons: 44          Time for 791 electrons: 3
Time for 2690 electrons: 128        Time for 1 electrons: 11
Time for 795 electrons: 48          Time for 1 electrons: 10
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 826 electrons: 83
Time for 1762 electrons: 80         Time for 2428 electrons: 2
Time for 2410 electrons: 124        Time for 1159 electrons: 17
Time for 454 electrons: 33          Time for 149 electrons: 10
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1355 electrons: 4
Time for 2912 electrons: 146        Time for 457 electrons: 25
Time for 1624 electrons: 85         Time for 523 electrons: 26
Time for 857 electrons: 54          Time for 561 electrons: 16
Time for 4517 electrons: 221        Time for 235 electrons: 43
Time for 2083 electrons: 113        Time for 708 electrons: 4
Time for 1268 electrons: 75         Time for 1388 electrons: 51
Time for 7548 electrons: 358        Time for 369 electrons: 3
Time for 557 electrons: 40          Time for 403 electrons: 7
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1234 electrons: 13
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 3203 electrons: 13
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 262 electrons: 27
Time for 1167 electrons: 65         Time for 444 electrons: 43
Time for 1410 electrons: 77         Time for 686 electrons: 7
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 7654 electrons: 26
Time for 4490 electrons: 412        Time for 731 electrons: 23
Time for 3093 electrons: 146        Time for 1336 electrons: 77
Time for 1170 electrons: 67         Time for 2117 electrons: 111
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 1750 electrons: 96
Time for 1 electrons: 8             Time for 1089 electrons: 58
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 3823 electrons: 185
Time for 1 electrons: 7             Time for 996 electrons: 54
Time for 713 electrons: 45          Time for 1 electrons: 7
Time for 973 electrons: 57          Time for 1 electrons: 8
```

Comment: This is usually what is happening when the work between threads is not well balanced or that some threads are synchronized (eg. they reach a critical section or a barrier). If `schedule(dynamic)` did not change the problem, it is likely due to synchronizations. But it could also be due to a too small `some_constant` value. Alternatively, this pattern can happen when you do some IO operations. Anyway, we need *more information* about what are precisely the computations (and the value of `some_constant`) to help you further.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I put in the exact code that I am running. Please let me know if more details are needed. I don't want to add more comments and make the post jammed with unnecessary details, but I can definitely add them if needed.

Comment: How long does one loop iteration take on average?

Comment: The variable privacy should be considered also. If many shared variables are read in the same time, a race problem might rise. For instance inf xe1... are not array (or small array), I suggest to use firstprivate(xe1,....) such to create a copy for each thread and avoid access to shared memory. Also could you let us know what is the statut of &sensor and calculate_signal? does &sensor change within the loop? same for calculate_signal?

Comment: if the number of electron end points is very different from one index to another, then you could have a load-balancing issue, even with a dynamic schedule. Besides this I do not see anything wrong (apart from what @Noureddine pointed out) unless there is a race condition in the function or atomics or any critical section or false sharing in the called functions.

Comment: @Qubit I have added to my post some details regarding how long it takes to execute one iteration. Sorry it took so long to reply. I wanted to make sure I have the correct number instead of guessing.

Comment: @Noureddine thank you for your suggestion. I will test that now. Regarding your questions, both sensor and calculate_signal should not be affected by the for loop. calculate_signal is a boolean variable that I defined so that I don't have to type true or false twice whenever it needs to change, and sensor is a class that I defined outside of the for loop.

Comment: @Kane Billiot Then you can make a copy for each thread using firstprivate declaration. This might increase the use of your CPU, but you will never get 100%

Comment: If the use of CPU decreases with time during the execution. I wonder if your CPU temperature does not reach a value that might launch the bios brake which role is to slow down the execution such to don't damage the CPU. You can check this, and if true go to bios and increase the fan spead. Also, if you are calculating trajectories, it might be that the problem come from another function. For instance if the Poisson solver take a huge time and this latter is not parallelized. These routines might lead to this.

Comment: @Noureddine Modern processors uses [frequency scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling) to prevent any critical thermal throttling issues. This does not impact the activity of the threads, but could cause a small imbalance since some could be executed on cores with a higher frequency (mainly on Intel CPU with the turbo-boost). When a lot of cores are used, the frequency should be relatively stable (and lower than in sequential) for all the cores assuming they all do the same computation and unless they are stalling or sleeping (see pstates/cstates).

Comment: @KaneBilliot The huge difference of `np` between is likely the cause of what you observe. Is `aval.GetNumberOfElectronEndpoints()` and the code above this expensive? Also, how big is `AvalancheMicroscopic` in memory?

Comment: One of those 1 electron runs in the 10 thread version took 0 time, which is suspicious. In any case, there is some imbalance here, how long is the period where you see <100% utilisation (i.e. is it approximately last 5 minutes or so)?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't have an immediate answer regarding the memory. So, I'll look into that and get back to you. About the runtime, it is the typical amount that I usually get. I tried to make my code as efficient as I can, but I still haven't looked into the functions of the toolkit yet (e.g. GetNumberOfElectronEndpoints()).

Comment: @Qubit I found that to be strange as well, but I'm not sure how to approach that yet. The period of <100% utilization lasts throughout the whole execution. I only see all cores at 100% for the first ~1 minute or so.

Comment: One thing that worries me is how for instance 1 electron calculations go from 7-8s to 11-12s, now that could just be hyperthreading, if it is enabled. Though looking at that thread count I would almost assume it's already disabled. In that case I would suspect memory access or I/O, your threads might be contending for memory bandwith or maybe there's some false sharing or a lot of writing to disks... can't really say since I have no clue what those functions there do.

Comment: These xe1, xe2... they never seem to get set? Is there a reason they are defined outside the loop?

Comment: @Qubit those variables are set when the GetElectronEndpoint(...) is called. The function retrieve values and assign the values to the given variables.

Comment: Oh okay so that takes references then, well that's going to be an issue. All threads want to use the same shared variables, I suggest moving this inside or setting them to private in the omp pragma.

Comment: @Qubit I have tried to make those private by adding firstprivate(xe1, ye1, ...) to the end of the #pragma statement. I will try to move all the variables inside.

Comment: @Qubit both methods yield comparable results to when the variables are not made private.

Comment: As @Qubit is saying, you seem to have a whole bunch of races in this code. Many (most) of your variables should be declared inside the parallel region (so split it into a parallel region with a separate omp for after declaring the variables, or, add private declarations for them). (xe*, ye*, ze*, status, the time start/end, ...). So the code is broken and needs to be fixed before worrying about performance!

Comment: @JimCownie Thanks for the suggestion. I'm working on that now. Can you expand a little bit on your reply. What did you mean by "split it into a parallel region with a separate omp for after declaring the variables"?

Comment: Instead of writing `#pragma omp parallel for` split it into the two separate directives of which it is composed (`#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for`), then you can declare the per-thread variables which are only needed inside the parallel region between those two directives. `#pragma omp parallel for` is only there to save some typing in the case where you don't need anything between entering the parallel region and the loop, or after the loop.